# Is int(ceil(x)) well-behaved?

Tags: python, math, floating-point

If I have a floating point number x, which is within the range of [0, 10<sup>6</sup>], is it guaranteed in Python that int(ceil(x)) will be rounded up correctly?

It seems possible from what little I know that ceil may be rounded down leading to an incorrect result. Something like: x = 7.6, ceil(x)=7.999.., int(ceil(x))=7. Can that happen?

Comment: It would be trivial to write a test for this...

Comment: But the answer is: unless Python is broken, it should be fine.  Single-precision floats can exactly represent all integers up to roughly 2^24, which is about 16e6.

Comment: @Oli: It's trivial to write a test for whether it's guaranteed that Python does this? I don't see it, all I see is how to write a test for whether it works on Windows, or whatever OS you're using.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, that's true.

Comment: @Oli: maybe I'm too optimistic, but when I see questions like this I like to imagine that the questioner has already observed it to be true on their machine as far as they can test, but is hoping for a real guarantee :-)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Python floats should be double-precision internally, so they even can correctly represent all integers up to `2^53 = 9e15`.

Comment: @SteveJessop Specifically, "works in CPython on $cpu_family when compiled with $cflags for these values: ...". As Djikstra put it: Program testing can be a very effective way to show the presence of bugs, but it is hopelessly inadequate for showing their absence.

Comment: Example of a failure: `int(math.ceil(18014398509481985.5))` => `18014398509481984`.

Comment: @Robᵩ: That's not really a failure of `int` or `ceil`, though...

Comment: @Robᵩ Not a failure. The float parsed from the literal is 1.8014398509481984e+16 and its ceil is 18014398509481984. This error will never occur without literals.

Comment: @Oli - I used the word "failure" in the same intentionally imprecise way that the OP used "correctly." What I wrote is not a failure to meet a spec or to implement a design, but a failure to meet the user's expectation.

Comment: @Hyperboreus - Of course the same behavior will occur without the use of large numeric literals: `int(math.ceil((float(2**54) + 1.5))) == 2**54`.

Comment: @Robᵩ And again nothing to do with either ceil or int.

Comment: @Hyperboreus - Obviously it has nothing to do with `ceil` or `int`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth indeed, `for i in range(<large number>): assert i == int(ceil(float(i)))` seems to hold for as many numbers are I cared to compute. I don't see the reason for the bound you specify, can you provide the smallest example (>0) that fails?

Comment: @qarma: That bound comes from the size of the mantissa in single-precision float (although as pointed out, Python uses `double` internally, so it would be 2^53 instead).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A correctly implemented `ceil` returns the exact mathematical value of ceil(*x*), with no error. When IEEE 754, or any reasonable floating-point system, is in use, `ceil` is not subject to rounding errors.

This does not prevent adverse effects from sources other than the `ceil` function. For example, `ceil(1.000000000000000000000000000000001)` will return 1 because `1.000000000000000000000000000000001` is converted to a floating-point value before `ceil` is called, and that conversion rounds its result. Similarly, a conversion from `double` to `float` followed by a call to `ceil` may yield a value that is not the ceiling of the original `double` value.

The conversion of the result of `ceil` to `int` of course relies on the range of `int`. As long as the value is in range, the conversion should not change the value.

Comment: Note that in python3 the conversion is limited by the *float* precision, not the integer range, since integers have arbitrary size and thus *any* `float` representing an integer *can* be converted to an `int` exactly, but not the opposite.

Comment: @Bakuriu: This is true in Python 2, too:  `int(ceil(big_x))` will just return a `long` instead of an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Python's guarantee about the floating-point format for `float` isn't very strict. I think all it says is that it uses double, and in the case of CPython that's whatever the C compiler calls `double`.

For numbers up to a million you're fine. No floating-point format in practical use loses precision for integers that small. The C standard requires that `double` is OK up to 10 decimal digits.

What you've probably observed is that due to floating-point rounding `int(sum([1.1] * 10))` is 10, not 11. That's because `sum([1.1] * 10)` is `10.999999999999998`, not `11.0`.

The result of `ceil` is always exactly an integer, so it will never be rounded down by `int` (or if you like it will be rounded down, but doing so doesn't change it's value!)

Comment: It's true that the guarantees aren't strict, in theory.  In practice, though, you'd have to look very hard to find an instance of Python running on a platform where double wasn't the IEEE 754 binary64 format.  The biggest risk is probably bad OS implementations of ceil.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: well, I *hope* that I'd have to look very hard to find an OS with that bad of an implementation of `ceil`. It has one job, to find the first representable value greater than or equal to its input, that's an exact integer. So it really should not return a non-integer. I'm not in a position to conduct that survey, though: whether any OS has that buggy a libc vs whether I can get Python to compile on a platform with a software fp library that I've jiggered to use something other than binary64 for `double` :-)

Comment: Yes, I'd hope so too.  I've definitely seen bad implementations of the C `round` function recently (on fairly mainstream platforms, even);  I'd *hope* that `floor` and `ceil` are harder to get wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you want information about python's `float` you should check the [`sys.float_info`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info) function. In particular its documentation makes it quite clear the python `float`s act exactly like C `float`/`double`s and provide the same guarantees. In fact it links to [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) part of C's standard.

So python's guarantees are the same as C's double. If an integer can be represented exactly as float then `int(the_float)` will return the correct integer.
The problem is that for big enough `float`s not all integers can be represented exactly.

Rob's example:

```
int(math.ceil(18014398509481985.5)) => 18014398509481984
```

Is **not** a failure of `int` or `ceil`, but simply the fact that `18014398509481985.5` can *not* be represented exactly:

```
>>> 18014398509481985.5
1.8014398509481984e+16
```

In summary: if the ceiling of `x` can be represented exactly then `int(ceil(x))` *will* return the correct integer. Otherwise `int(x)` will return the integer returned by `ceil(x)` which need not be the "mathematical ceiling of `x`".

Currently, almost all computers conform to IEEE 754 and so you can be sure that `int(ceil(x))` returns the correct result according to the standard.

In embedded systems this might not be true but I'm not sure that python can even run on not-IEEE 754 compliant architectures.

---

If you do not trust what we can say you can always try to read the source code of `PyLong_FromDouble` in `Objects/longobject.c`:

```
PyObject *
PyLong_FromDouble(double dval)
{
    PyLongObject *v;
    double frac;
    int i, ndig, expo, neg;
    neg = 0;
    if (Py_IS_INFINITY(dval)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_OverflowError,
                        "cannot convert float infinity to integer");
        return NULL;
    }
    if (Py_IS_NAN(dval)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,
                        "cannot convert float NaN to integer");
        return NULL;
    }
    if (dval < 0.0) {
        neg = 1;
        dval = -dval;
    }
    frac = frexp(dval, &expo); /* dval = frac*2**expo; 0.0 <= frac < 1.0 */
    if (expo <= 0)
        return PyLong_FromLong(0L);
    ndig = (expo-1) / PyLong_SHIFT + 1; /* Number of 'digits' in result */
    v = _PyLong_New(ndig);
    if (v == NULL)
        return NULL;
    frac = ldexp(frac, (expo-1) % PyLong_SHIFT + 1);
    for (i = ndig; --i >= 0; ) {
        digit bits = (digit)frac;
        v->ob_digit[i] = bits;
        frac = frac - (double)bits;
        frac = ldexp(frac, PyLong_SHIFT);
    }
    if (neg)
        Py_SIZE(v) = -(Py_SIZE(v));
    return (PyObject *)v;
}
```

the code isn't a simple cast because long integers aren't represented as C doubles. And it seems like even in python2 there's no `PyInt_FromDouble`.

Answer (score 0):

It's often the case that there's rounding errors in floating point numbers, but that's only because not all numbers that are reprensentable in decimal are perfectly represented in binary. Those numbers that *can* be represented exactly won't have any rounding applied. That is the case for integer values up to 2**53, so with only 6 digits you will be safe.

The lowest positive integer value that can't be represented exactly in a `float` is 9007199254740993.

Comment: All floats are perfectly represented in binary. But most real numbers cannot be represented as floats.

Comment: And most reals cannot be represented at all, given that the subset of reals that we can represent is countable.

Comment: @aka.nice: even worse, it's finite. We can define schemes to represent countably many values given unlimited resources, but we don't have unlimited resources :-)